# Need a Click and Drag solution using Vanilla Javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

I have to do a click-and-drag solution for a background image in Vanilla Javascript for a project. I found this solution using jQuery in Codepen. Can anyone help me with a Vanilla Javascript version of it?

```
    Draggable.create(".box", {
        bounds:$container,
        edgeResistance:0.65,
        type:"x,y",
        throwProps:true,
    autoScroll:true,
    });
```

https://codepen.io/johndownie/pen/vxOwrx

The project is going to be in Vue but if I can get a solution in plain HTML, CSS and Javascript, it will be great.

Comment: HTML has an [drag & drop api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this approach. It is not as smooth as jquery draggable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body,
      html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background-color: black;
      }

      #container {
        background-color: #333;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }

      #box {
        background-image: url(http://www.vgmaps.com/NewsArchives/April2005/LegendOfZelda-Link%27sAwakeningAdvance-Koholint.png);
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
      }

      #box:hover {
          cursor: move;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    dragElement(document.getElementById("container"));

    function dragElement(elmnt) {
      var pos1 = 0,
        pos2 = 0,
        pos3 = 0,
        pos4 = 0;
      if (document.getElementById("box")) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById("box").onmousedown =
          dragMouseDown;
      } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }

      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }

      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2 + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1 + "px";
      }

      function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks yeah this is not very smooth. The dragging is not controllable.

Comment: Yes it's glitchy